# Scrapy Installation error exit status 2

Tags: windows, scrapy, build-tools

I'm trying to install Scrapy on my windows device. I originally got the "windows VS build tools 2015 not installed error" that has been posted on here multiple times. I tried numerous solutions that were posted on here but they didn't work. After downloading the build tools, I'm now getting this error:

[image: Error screenshot]

I've searched and tried most of the solutions on here. If someone can redirect me to the solution or point out my error that would be great.

Comment: in C://Users, your user folder is "Matt Jones" or "MATTJO~1"? because if it is the latter, the tilde (~) might be causing problems

Comment: Interesting... I hadn't noticed that, thanks for pointing that out. I never made a user folder MATTJO~1 nor does it appear in file explorer (I've enabled show hidden files). However, when I navigate through the command prompt, it seems to be an exact copy of my Matt Jones user folder. Regardless, I was able to reinstall miniconda on my device and the scrapy installation worked that way